# No matching function call error with usage of, lambda expressions and std::function.

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am trying to use this lambda expression in my code. And looks like something's wrong with definition of functor or lambda.

I believe the lambda expression is true. but I can't satisfy the prototype of function I defined.

Function definition:

```
    template<typename E, typename container> 
void for_each(Iterator<E,container> begin, std::function<void(E&)> fun)
{
    do // does the given unary functor to elements 
    {  //from starting iterator 'til the end.
        fun(*begin);
        begin = begin.next();
    }while(begin.hasNext());

    fun(*begin);
}
```

And caller:

```
  for_each(c.iterator(), [&](E& e){add(e);});
```

I except achieve this function call with lambda expression. But compiler says "error: no matching function for call to .."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lambda is not `std::function`, so deduction fails.

You might simply pass generic `Functor`:

```
template<typename E, typename container, typename F> 
void for_each(Iterator<E, container> begin, F&& fun)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ty, it worked. But I was trying to imitate this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353210/usage-and-syntax-of-stdfunction) example. What part did I miss?

Comment: Issue is with deduction, you might call it successfully `for_each<E>(c.iterator(), [&](E& e){add(e);});` with your version. lambda can convert to `std::function`, but it is unrelated type.

Comment: A curious decision to pass the function-object by reference instead of by value, like the standard-library does. If indirection is actually wanted, that's what `std::ref()` is for.

Comment: @Deduplicator: pre-c++11, there are no forward references. now interfaces use them, for example [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke), [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), ... (which still might use `std::reference_wrapper`).

Answer (score 0):

Issues with the code and Possible solution approaches below:

**1. A [`Lambda expression`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) is not [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), it can only be stored in an object of type [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).**

*Approach: (With your existing signature):*

```
std::function<void()> f = []() -> void { // do something };
for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), f);
```

**2. Better solution would be to use a [`Callable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) as a parameter (Go to end of the answer).**

**3. If you want to pull up your own version of `for_each`, why not follow the implementation that is consistent with other algorithms or for that matter with the implementation of `for_each` in the algorithm header.**

*Does all you want and is also consistent with other standard algorithms: [en.cppreference.com/algorithms/for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):*

```
    template<class InputIt, class UnaryFunction>
    constexpr UnaryFunction for_each(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f)
    {
      for (; first != last; ++first) {
        f(*first);
      }
      return f;
    }
```

Comment: Using a forwarding reference isn't going to prevent you from being *"able to reuse the function object"* unless you `forward` the reference. And using an lvalue reference instead prevents you from calling your function with a lambda as an argument `for_each(x, y, [](...){...});`, which is not a good thing...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Incorporated the suggested changes. Must have sneaked in as I had to type it in due to some issues while copying. :p