# Passing function as template argument to a member function

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to pass function as template argument to a function in a class, but there is some mistake. The code is giving an error `error: missing template arguments before 'obj'`. How can I fix this so that it compiles?

```
#include<iostream>
double sum_fun(const double &a, const double &b)
{ std::cout<<a+b<<"\n"; }

template <typename F>
class B 
{
    public:
    void fb()(F f1)
    {
        f1(10.1,10.2);
    }
};

int main()
{
    B obj(sum_fun); //error
    obj.fb(); //error
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding of how classes work.

```
int main()
{
    B obj(sum_fun); // calls B constructor with parameter `sum_fun`
    obj.fb(); // calls member function B::fb() with no parameters
    return 0;
}
```

Both lines raise an error as

1. Your class has no constructor which takes a single parameter.
2. `void fb()(F f1)` is illegal syntax. To declare a member function, use only one set of parentheses: either `void fb()` or `void fb(F f1)`. The latter is incorrect in our case, as your member function call `obj.fb()` passes no parameters.

To fix this, write up a constructor, store the function as a member variable, and use that variable in the function `fb()`.

```
template <typename F>
class B 
{
public:
    // constructor, initialises member `m_func` through member initialisation
    B(F func) : m_func(func) {}

    void fb()
    {
        m_func(10.1,10.2);
    }

private:
    F m_func;

};
```

In C++17, thanks to automatic template deduction, no errors are now emitted. But in lower standards (e.g. C++11), template deduction is lacking and thus, the full templated type needs to be specified when declaring `obj`.

So in standards below C++17, the main function should be:

```
int main()
{
    // C++11: using a function pointer to denote type
    B<double(*)(const double&, const double&)> obj(sum_fun);

    // ok in C++17, looks cleaner too
    // B obj(sum_fun);

    obj.fb();
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `double(*)(const double&, const double&)` is a [function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer), i.e. a pointer to a function which returns a `double` and takes two parameters, both of type `const double&`. Function pointers may be considered as a type, which satisfies the template (`template<typename F>`).

Just like we do `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<double>`, we can also do `std::vector<double(*)(const double&, const double&)>` to denote a vector of functions returning `double` and taking `const double&` as parameters.

And by the way, `sum_fun` also raises a warning: nothing is returned even though the return type is `double`... better specify `void` as the return type instead.

[***C++11 Demo***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc16ef229fc7acf0)
[***C++17 Demo***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03f5ec4d76612a6c)

---

> Is it possible to pass function as argument directly to `B::fb()` instead of creating constructor `B::B(F)` and storing in local variable?

Certainly.

```
#include <iostream>

void sum_fun(const double& a, const double& b)
{
    std::cout << a+b << "\n";
}

template <typename F>
class B 
{
public:
    void fb(F func)
    {
        func(10.1,10.2);
    }
};

int main()
{
    B<void(*)(const double&, const double&)> obj;
    obj.fb(sum_fun);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the member function `fb` now takes a single parameter `func`, which we then call. Note also that in C++17, we now can't instantiate the `obj` with `B obj;` because this would be ambiguous and the template can't be deduced automatically. Instead, we need to specify the full type `B<void(*)(const double&, const double&)>`.

However, a recommended alternative over function pointers is to use [`std::function`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353210/usage-and-syntax-of-stdfunction), which is more versatile and offers a more readable syntax. ([*`std::function` Demo*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9c1dae9a3c1801e))

Comment: The other problem is that he needs to specify `F` when he creates the object.

Comment: @0x499602D2 op does use `F` (in `void fb()(F f1)`) but the syntax is wrong... I'm probably misunderstanding your comment. Some clarification would help. :|

Comment: He does `B obj` when it should be `B<type-of-function> obj`

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ah, I see. I was compiling with C++17 (which doesn't complain about `B obj`). Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @TrebledJ can you comment on 2 things : (1) Is it possible to pass function as argument directly to `B::fb()` instead of creating constructor `B::B(F)` and storing in local variable? (2) Can you explain what is `B<double(*)(const double&, const double&)>` and how it works? I am particularly confused with `double(*)` Thanks !

Comment: @ewr3243 I've edited and expanded my answer to answer your questions. In short, (1) Yes, it is possible; (2) It's a function pointer... something I don't often see used. I usually use std::function instead. Hope the edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 you're allowed to use `auto` in template paramter list:

```
template <auto F>
class B
{
    public:
    void fb()
    {
        F(10.1,10.2);
    }
};
```

You can then do `B<sum_fun>`:

```
int main()
{
    B<sum_fun> obj{};
    obj.fb();
    return 0;
}
```