# C++ How to simplify member functions that only differ in function call

Tags: c++, function, simplify

I need to create 10 functions that are very long and identical in every way except for a single line of code in each function. This single line of code is a function call.
Is there a way to condense into one function?
ex.

```
int doSomethingOne()
{
...
one();
...
}

int doSomethingtwo()
{
... // same as one
two();
... // same as one
}
```

Comment: Pass in a pointer to a function (or reference to a `std::function`) that does that specialized stuff. eg: `int doSomething(void (*func)()) { ... func() ... }` call it with `doSomething(one);`

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: Seems like resource acquisition. Can you give more details about the similar part of the code?

Comment: *Is there a way..* If there was no way, programmers would leave C++ alone and move on to another language.  What you should have done is created a single function, remove that one line of code, and research how to pass callable objects so that the single function knows how to invoke the callable object.  That is basically what @user4581301 suggested, but there are multiple ways to achieve the general idea presented in the first comment.

Comment: Was looking for a duplicate. Very simple example: https://godbolt.org/z/YTfTvqc7K

Comment: Semi-duplicates: [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840501/4581301), [What is the purpose of std::function and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20353210/4581301). Definitely read as far as answer 2 in the second link because it shows you how to do stuff with [capturing lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)  which comes in very handy.

Comment: [Pointers to Member Functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) covers some more advanced tricks for doing this with class members.

Comment: "I need to create 10 functions that are very long and identical in every way except for a single line of code" - Sounds like you should abstract all that identical code into a new function so that your 10 functions become 1 call to the shared function and then 1 line of new code. That would make all of your 10 functions just 2 lines long, which should be manageable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl not exactly, the function is a little more complicated. My "10 functions" are in a loop and called x times and each return value is pushed into a vector.  Your suggestion would only save a few lines of code.  TedLyngmo's solution is very helpful but I want to know if there is a way to do the same for member functions.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a function template doing all the common parts and calling a user-provided function in the middle of it all:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class Func>
int doSomething(Func&& func) {
    // do all the common stuff before calling func
    func();
    // do all the common stuff after calling func
    return 0;
}

void one() { std::cout << "One\n"; }
void two() { std::cout << "Two\n"; }

int doSomethingOne() { return doSomething(&one); }
int doSomethingtwo() { return doSomething(&two); }

int main() {
    doSomethingOne();
    doSomethingtwo();
    doSomething(+[]{ std::cout << "Anything goes\n"; });
}
```

Output:

```
One
Two
Anything goes
```

Comment: Just note that the code of the function template for `doSomething` will be duplicated in memory for each instantiation of the template. If you want to avoid that, remove the template and make `doSomething` take a `std::function` or plain function pointer as a parameter, so there is only 1 copy of `doSomething` in memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There _may_ be multiple instantiations. I just removed them so now there's only one :-)

Comment: [80s Flashback](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqcLjcSloXs)

Comment: If you're going to accept `Func` as a forwarding reference, you probably want `std::forward` it. Otherwise, you could just accept it by value. Also, is it really necessary to `+` the lambda? It would work without it. It really seems to me like the `+` is just premature (compilation speed) optimization and you should have kept your original version, or gone all the way and used function pointers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Does this work for member functions?
 class Test
{
  public:
    void one() { std::cout << "One\n"; }
    void two() { std::cout << "Two\n"; }
};

Comment: @JanSchultke _"Otherwise, you could just accept it by value"_ - No, that wouldn't work with non-copyable functors.  The `+` was added to just get one instance of the function - but unless the function is big, it'll probably be inlined in the end anyway so I doubt the `+` makes much of a differance.

Comment: @quant Sure: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/3147YhGfs)

Comment: @TedLyngmo any non-copyable function could be wrapped in a lambda that forwards the parameters, so it's not a big issue. The standard library also accepts function objects by value all over the place. Currently, you would instantiate three separate `doSomething` for an lvalue function pointer, rvalue function pointer, and lvalue function (all to the same function). If your goal is to reduce instantiations, then forwarding references should be the first thing to replace.

Comment: It's a good solution nonetheless and I didn't want to bikeshed this much over it. It's just odd design to me; that's all.

Comment: @JanSchultke No worries! I am not really bothered about many instantiations (unless I'm targeting a platform with limited memory/storage) and replaced the two I had before the edit with one mostly for fun :) I personally like the forwarding references because of their rather promiscuous nature. In a real situation I'd probably constrain it somehow to get a nicer compilation error if it isn't fit for the function it's passed to.

Answer (score 1):

> [..] that are very long and identical

You might create sub-functions, so

```
Data preamble()
{
    // ...
}
void postamble(Data& data)
{
    // ...
}

int doSomethingOne()
{
    auto data = preamble();
    one();
    postamble(data);
}

int doSomethingtwo()
{
    auto data = preamble();
    two();
    postamble(data);
}
```